# Should I use was or were with a two-item list?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

In the sentence, "*Jonathan Oldstyle and Diedrich Knickerbocker (was, were) two of Irving's pen name*" do I use was or were?

Comment: Use a pronoun in place of the names... Which pronoun would you use?

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward answer is that, since there are two subjects, the subject is plural, and you should use *were*:

> Ann and Mark **were** at the baseball game.
>
> Milk and eggs **were** required to make the recipe.
>
> The Lannisters and the Starks **were** friends of my family.

There isn't much more to say about this simple case, but if you are interested, you can read more about how to conjugate the verb [when using compound subjects like "milk and cookies".](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-subjects)

Answer (score 1):

## Were

> Jonathan Oldstyle and Diedrich Knickerbocker ***were*** two of Irving's pen name***s***

**Were** is (in this case) the 3rd person, **plural** past form of the verb *be*.

**Was** is (in this case) the 3rd person, **singular** past form of the verb *be*.

You have two subjects, `Jonathan Oldstyle and Diedrich Knickerbocker`, so the **plural** form is correct.

---

Here is an example where the singular form, **was**, would be correct:

> Jonathan Oldstyle ***was*** one of Irving's pen names.

---

**Note:** use the plural *names*, rather than `name`, because you are talking about a collective of pen names, by saying `two of`, you are implying that there are many (more than one) pen names.

Comment: Explaining why is more valuable than answering the question. If they know **why** this is correct, they will be able to address all such issues in the future. It's the difference between giving a person a ghoti and teaching a person to ghoti. :)

Comment: @Catija Absolutely. That's what I'll be dedicating some time to now. The question doesn't ask **why**, it just asks which word to use, so I'm happy getting the direct answer out ASAP, and then explaining in detail why in an edit.

Comment: a collective of pen names doesn't mean much. The reason the sentence takes /were/ is simply because it has two subjects.

Comment: @Lambie I said exactly that ***"You are referring to two pen names, so the plural form is correct.*** ... The "collective of pen names" is there as a ***NOTE***, even labelled and bold in the answer, to explain why *name* is a typo, there should be an -*s* added.

Comment: I read your explanation twice and did not see a clear explanation. It is not that you are **referring to two pen names**. It is that the two pen names **are** the subjects of the sentence.

Comment: @Lambie That's a more valid correction, but your first remark was about "collective of pens", which in my answer is there to explain a minor typo in the question, to explain why I changed it from *pen name* to *pen names*.  It's not there to explain why **were** is correct, hence the ***NOTE:*** label.

Comment: It's getting even more confusing to me. Sorry. By using the verb /refer/, the question is not being answered. In grammar explanations, the most simple explanation is: compound subjects or two subjects call for a plural verb in the clause.

Comment: @Lambie It becomes circular because I'm repeating myself (this would make the third time). Your initial remark was about **collective of pen names** (read your first comment to confirm), and now you've changed your qualm to be about a different part of my answer **referring to two pen names**. So, what's happened is you criticised one part of my answer, I correctly refuted the criticism, by clarifying that it's a ***NOTE:** to explain the "pen name" typo, and then you swiftly changed your "confusion" to be about a different part. Make up your mind next time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48786/discussion-between-lambie-and-ghoti-and-chips).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is were. Any sentence with two subjects takes a plural verb. The **cat and the dog** **were** sitting on the fence.

**Jonathan Oldstyle** and **Diedrich Knickerbocker were** two of Irving's pen name.

**Jonathan Oldstyle** and **Diedrich Knickerbocker** are the **subjects of the sentence**.

Comment: Any downvote here is just spite. OP beware...:)